# Script for updating table after checking it row by row

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with four columns. Column3 should be equal to Column1 and Column2 is always equal to Column4. Please give me a script that will check my table row by row and upon checking, if there are rows in column1 and column3 that are not equal, it will update rows in column3 so it will be equal to column 1. our database is oracle 9i and i have little experience with sql so im hoping that you can help me out.

This is sample data of table1 PACKAGE_DEALS (but this table consists of 5 more columns)

```
ID_NO   | ID_NAME 
--------+--------
1886103 | BMW 
1884247 | Ferrari 
3177964 | Honda 
 381677 | Volvo
```

And this is for table2 INDIVIDUAL_DEAL (this table also has two 4 more columns)

```
PLAN_ID | PLAN_NAME 
--------+----------
3177964 | Honda 
3177957 | Honda 
1886103 | BMW 
1886103 | BMW 
1884247 | Ferrari 
1884247 | Ferrari 
 381436 | Volvo 
 381677 | Volvo
```

And I would like a script that will make table2 like this.

```
PLAN_ID | PLAN_NAME 
--------+----------
3177964 | Honda 
3177964 | Honda 
1886103 | BMW 
1886103 | BMW 
1884247 | Ferrari 
1884247 | Ferrari 
 381677 | Volvo 
 381677 | Volvo
```

The PLAN_ID in table2 should always be equal to the ID_NO in table1.
Table2 is used often and many have accessed to it, so there are datas that are not correct so I would like to have a script that will update it and have right datas in place.

```
update table1
set col3 = (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1)
where col3 <> (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1);
```

i have used the update script above given by thorsten (and I'm thankful for that) and it says too many rows to be updated. is there another way to do this?

Comment: with any SQL question please provide a working test case, which includes create statements, few insert statements as sample data and your expected output. Meanwhile, you can have a look at MERGE statement http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_9016.htm

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a script for this. A simple UPDATE statement will suffice. It will update all records WHERE a certain condition is met (column1 being different from column3 in your case).

Just try to write it yourself. You will see how easy this is. If you happen to have issues with this though, then write again and tell us what particular problem you are facing.

EDIT: From your comments it shows that you didn't describe your problem correctly. You are not talking of a *table* where one column doesn't match the other, but a *query* where one column doesn't match the other. What you want to do is more or less this:

```
update table1
set col3 = (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1)
where col3 <> (select col1 from table2 where key2 = table1.key1);
```

So you'd write the same query twice, one in the SET clause, once in the WHERE clause.

For this situation Oracle offers **updateble queries**:

```
update 
(
  select table1.col3, table2.col1
  from table1 
  join table2 on (table1.key1 = table2.key2)
)
set col3 = col1
where col3 <> col1;
```

This is only possible when the dbms sees it as guaranteed that the query won't retrieve more than one result record per table1 record. Sometimes it happens that *you* know this to be guaranteed, but *Oracle* doesn't. It depends on unique indexes and complexity probably. So good luck here.

If the updatable query approach fails, there is still the option with having the query in both the SET and WHERE clause.

Comment: actually, the data in my table comes from two different tables.column1 and column2 came from table1 and column3 and column4 came from table 2. I just made a query that joins these two table so i can compare them ( and that's the table i am describing above). is a simple update can do this? thanks for the help.

Comment: and by the way, datas in the two different tables are updated everyday.

Comment: thank you. i'll try the query above and let you know if its successful.. :) you saved my day.

Comment: i forgot to ask what's that key1 and key2 represent? thanks again

Comment: Well, you join two tables. There will be columns you join them by. Often a primary key in one table and a foreign key in the other. key1 and key2 are just placeholders for your join criteria. After all, I don't know your query. This is just a simple example to illustrate what I am saying.

Comment: i provide additional data above. sorry, i dont know how i can make it more readable (the tables, i mean). im new here so putting image is not allowed for me at least i have 10 reputation. so, i hope you will continue to help me @Thorsten

Comment: Well, the main question is: Why do you hold data redundantly at all? I would just remove column PLAN_NAME from INDIVIDUAL_DEAL and you're done for all time. If you want to stick to your database design with recurring updates necessary then use UPDATE as I explained above. Just replace the table and column names with yours.

Comment: As to formatting: You can use HTML tags such as `<pre>` and `</pre>`. (Or use the code button `{}` instead, but this might also add some colors you don't want). Press the "edited ... ago" link on your request above to see what edits I've made.

Comment: thank you again.. i follow your lead but im concerned with the key1 and key2. how do I obtain this?? sorry I am a complete beginner at this.

Comment: and i can't delete that column in INDIVIDUAL_DEALS because the access in PACKAGE_DEALS is limited to certain people only.

Comment: Key1/key2: What do you join your tables by? PACKAGE_DEALS.ID_NO and INDIVIDUAL_DEAL.PLAN_ID obviously. What else? Not knowing your tables I simply had to invent names and decided for key1 and key2.

Comment: Access right: This is no good reason for redundant data. You already notice that redundant data in a database is a plague. Create a view instead: `CREATE VIEW V_PACKAGE_DEALS AS SELECT ID_NO, ID_NAME FROM PACKAGE_DEALS;` and give those users read permission on it.

Comment: ok. thank you so much.. sorry for disturbing you this much. thanks again. :)

Comment: ora-01779 has appeared using the second query above but your first query works out just fine. So I am overthinking when I assume that a cursor for loop will solve the problem. Anyways, thanks again to you @Thorsten.